# iPhone does not receive UDP data over WiFi

Tags: iphone, udp, wifi

With a WiFi connection, UDP data is not received. It stops at:

```
recvfrom(sock, buf, RECV_BUF_SIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&rAddr, (SOCK_LEN*)&len);
```

When I run the same program in iPhone simulator over ethernet it works well.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [man](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/recvfrom.2.html) page.

Like so:

```
  recvfrom(mSock,recvBuff,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen);
```

providing the parameter values you are setting are correct try this in your case try:

```
  recvfrom(sock, buf, RECV_BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&rAddr, &len);
```

Comment: Signatures are redundant on SO, every post already has your name attached at the bottom.  See [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for more details.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer - the only change you seem to be suggesting is changing one cast and removing another cast. In C / ObjectiveC, that's not going to make any difference to how the code runs.

Comment: joseph hav you tried NSLogging the variables first to make sure they have the right data contained within them? do that as a test

Comment: Hi , when i send broadcast data over udp is not received in iphone,then i altered and then send the data over unicast (Given my ipaddress) then it receives udp data over wifi.Is anyother suggestion ?